# What's the meaning of this sentence from forbes?

Tags: meaning-in-context, headlinese

> Let The Fixes Feel Like Their Own

[This](http://www.forbes.com/sites/stevenberglas/2011/03/22/how-to-tell-someone-theyre-wrong-and-make-them-feel-good-about-it/#2715e4857a0b78c7e2242dc7) is an article from Forbes. In the last point, it says you give the person a suggestion and then somehow it would feel like their own solution. I don't understand how that should feel like their own suggestion.

EDIT: Last point added below:

> Let The Fixes Feel Like Their Own. Chelsea A. Grayson, a partner in
>   the Los Angeles office of Jones Day’s mergers-and-acquisitions
>   practice, is acutely sensitive to saying, “You’re wrong” in a
>   constructive manner. “After I present my approach to someone I solicit
>   feedback to ensure buy-in,” she says. “When I get it, and we
>   concretize a plan, I often characterize it as theirs. If people feel
>   you support their fundamental views and value them, achieving buy-in
>   is easy and natural.”

Comment: *Solution* is not the same thing as *suggestion*, and embracing a solution is not the same thing as suggesting a solution.

Comment: @StoneyB Agreed! Could you just explain the last point in this article? I probably didn't understand it well.

Comment: You should quote that "last point" in your question, so Answerers don't have to look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume OP finds the cited text confusing because it "reverses" the roles of the relevant subject and object.

Obviously the ***fixes*** (solutions) can't actually ***feel*** anything at all, since they're effectively abstract concepts, with no mind of their own. But we often use this apparently illogical construction in English...

> *This jacket feels like mine.*
>    ...obviously means...
>    *This jacket feels **to me** like it's my jacket*

---

So in OP's case, we can paraphrase

> *Let **the fixes** feel like their own*
>    ...as...
>   *Let **them** feel as though **the fixes** are their own*

(If people think they worked something out *for themselves,* rather than being *told* the solution, they remember it better, use it more appropriately, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

**Grayson** gives a suggestion to her client and then solicits **feedback**. Using this **looped process**, one can presume the solution is more customised for the client making it **tailor-made**.  **Grayson** then goes further by saying the solution (**fix**) was of the the client's own making.

The buy-in occurs from the **customisation of the solution**, not just the feedback *pre se*.

There are various **techniques** to get **buy-in** from participants and they are usually taught in **business management** courses.  The main point is to **lead** the client to a solution, not **tell** them what the answer is.

The sentence

> Let The Fixes Feel Like Their Own

Means

> let the fixes feel like ***they belong*** to the client